# incremental backup manager for filesystem and database on php

Tags: backup

I am searching for a php/mysql based backup management system for files (incremental) and DB (incl. Cron-algorythm).
I would like to manage my backups and (if possible) have a restore function for DB and for files.

Thanks in advance!!!

**UPDATE**

I am searching a Linux based solution (thats why I wrote cron... as in cron jobs) where I will store backups for Website and Webapp projects (so mostly ascii files and images). And the backups should be stored on the same machine.

Comment: Backup solution you mean? check bareos.org

Comment: Do I interpret the term "cron" correctly in indicating you want that solution for a Linux system? Shall those backups be stored on the same machine – or if not, what OS is running on the "backup storage machine"? Are solutions requiring a little scripting acceptable? If so, I could share the solution I've set up :)

Comment: @lzzy: yes please, this would be interesting!